Fasttext MUSE Classification - how to know if I am overfitting?
I am working on a project to classify news, and I am using fasttext for classification. I have 4 classes in total.
I have pretty cool results, and actually I am afraid they are too cool to be true.
I have trained my model like this
modelc = fasttext.train_supervised(input="C:/Users/Documenti/df_train_classification1.csv", epoch=25, lr =0.123) 
After doing all the predictions on the test set my confusion matrix looks like this:
       precision    recall  f1-score   support

  __label__1       0.99      0.90      0.94       112
  __label__2       0.91      0.99      0.95       118
  __label__3       0.97      0.97      0.97       120
  __label__4       0.98      0.97      0.98       148

    accuracy                           0.96       498
   macro avg       0.96      0.96      0.96       498
weighted avg       0.96      0.96      0.96       498

I have chosen the parameters based on the loss (manually I set up loss-epochs combo, and looked on the avg loss) , but after reading this article By what criteria do we find out that fasttext unsupervised is well trained? I am very unsure about this.
I have read this stackoverflow article Regularization in Fasttext  about overfitting, but still I don't know how to check if I am overfitting or not.
I know from theory that if the model performs bad on test and very good on train, then it is overfitting. But here it looks like it is good on test.
Maybe this is just paranoia, but I am very doubtful of having this hight performance.
Also,  based on an answer I found (cannot find the link), and on theory,I know that larger is the window of words ,larger is the probality of overfitting. So , I have tried with different wordngrams - the default is 1, I have try with 5, and the model is doing worse, indeed the precision dropped down to 0.60.
I am not sure that this quick check was enough to be sure I am not overfitting with my model.
The other problem is that I dont know how to plot the learning rate or epochs vs the error (or in this case, the accuracy), I am pretty new to python.
Many thanks to all for reading, and if you have any idea , comment or just a tip, please let me know.
